# I am studying Python Class and method. But I don't know whats wrong with my code. Need help. Result for P3, P4 do not work

Tags: python

I am studying Python Class and method. But I don't know whats wrong with my code. Need help. Result for P3, P4 do not work.

I made Point class and Rectangle class. The code works out for r1 = Rectangle(p1, p2). But, does not work out for r2 = Rectangle(p3, p4). Can someone please explain me what is wrong and how to fix the code. Thank you

```
class Point:

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
           
class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2
    
    def get_area(self):
        w = max(p1.x, p2.x)
        h = max(p1.y, p2.y)
        return w*h
    
    def get_perimeter(self):
        w = max(p1.x, p2.x)
        h = max(p1.y, p2.y)
        if w == h:
            return w*4
        else:
            return abs(p2.x - p1.x)*2 + abs(p2.y - p1.y)*2
    
    def is_square(self):
        w = max(p1.x, p2.x)
        h = max(p1.y, p2.y)
        if w == h:
            return True
        else:
            return False

p1 = Point(1,3)
p2 = Point(3,1)
r1 = Rectangle(p1, p2)
print(r1.get_area())
print(r1.get_perimeter())
print(r1.is_square())

p3 = Point(3,7)
p4 = Point(6,4)
r2 = Rectangle(p3, p4)  
print(r2.get_area())
print(r2.get_perimeter())
print(r2.is_square())
```

Comment: You are repeatedly taking the max, when you should be taking the absolute value of the difference.   The width, for example, is `abs(p1.x - p2.x)`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "The code works out for r1 = Rectangle(p1, p2). But, does not work out for r2 = Rectangle(p3, p4). Can someone please explain me what is wrong and how to fix the code." This is not an answerable question as it stands. Please read [ask] and [mre] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, try to track down the problem; and if you can't solve it yourself then make sure to explain clearly: **what happens exactly** when you run the code (show the output)? **What should happen instead**, and how is that different?

Comment: In your own words: where the code says `w = max(p1.x, p2.x)`, what do you think this means? Why is the variable named `w` - what is it supposed to represent? What does `max` mean, and how is it supposed to help you compute the result?

Comment: (Hint: where the code says `return abs(p2.x - p1.x)*2 + abs(p2.y - p1.y)*2` in `get_perimeter`, how does that work? What does each part of that mean?) (Hint: if you have to write two more functions `get_width` and `get_height`, what code should they have? Can you see how you could use those functions to implement the other ones?)

Comment: There are many things wrong with this code. Please try to write less code at a time, and *make sure each part works* before moving on to the next step. When you encounter a problem, please try to debug it first. Stack Overflow is not a debugging service, nor a discussion forum; we cannot simply take a code dump and fix the problems.

Comment: "I am studying Python Class and method." Another useful tip: try to write code using ordinary functions first, and make sure you have logic that actually makes sense, before trying to fit it into classes.

Answer (score -1):

Inside of the Rectangle class you are accessing the global scope p1 and p2 variables. All the class functions should use self.p1 and self.p2

Comment: While correct, this is far from the only problem with the code.